# Highlights and notes are not save to my Clipping file

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, annotations

I regularly delete the My Clippings file in my Kindle when it gets too big. Usually a new one appears the next time I make a highlight or a note, containing just that one highlight or note.

However, after the last delete, I am unable to save highlights and notes. When I make one a new My Clippings file is created, but it is empty and it remains so no matter how many highlights or notes I make. The highlights and notes are saved somewhere, since they remain in the book, but they are not logged in the My Clippings file.

I've tried deleting it again, but the same thing happens. I've also tried restarting the Kindle after and before the new file is created, but it doesn't help.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, much to my surprise, I solved this.

I had to delete my (empty) Clippings file, then connect to the internet, then make a highlight. Apparently the issue was somehow caused by synchronization, because after doing this my highlights and notes appear on my Clippings file again, even if I'm not connected to the internet.